# How to focus the next field?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield, flutter-textinputfield, flutter-button, flutter-focus-node

I have a page with several text fields, I used [`FocusTraversalGroup`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusTraversalGroup-class.html) so the fields are focused in the desired order when pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>. See:

[image: With tab]

Now, when I click on the icon button `next`, I want to send the focus to the next field.
For example, if I click on the icon button `next` of the text field `3`, I want the text field 4 to be focused. For that, I tried to use `focusNode.nextFocus()`, but the focus is sent to the text field 1 instead.

See the video:

[image: click on next]

Here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: FocusTraversalGroup(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text('1')),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text('2')),
                    ),
                    const _Field(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text('3')),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text('4')),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text('5')),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 20),
            Expanded(
              child: FocusTraversalGroup(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text('6')),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text('7')),
                    ),
                    const _Field(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text('8')),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text('9')),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(label: Text('10')),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Field extends StatefulWidget {
  const _Field({
    this.decoration,
  });

  final InputDecoration? decoration;

  @override
  State<_Field> createState() => __FieldState();
}

class __FieldState extends State<_Field> {
  final focusNodeText = FocusNode();
  final focusNodeButton = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNodeText.dispose();
    focusNodeButton.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FocusTraversalGroup(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            decoration: widget.decoration,
            focusNode: focusNodeText,
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  focusNode: focusNodeButton,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_next),
                  onPressed: () {
                    focusNodeButton.nextFocus();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i just ran your code on my iPhone, it's worked fine, perhaps is your simulator's problem?

Comment: I'm running this macOS or Web (to use `tab`). Maybe it is a platform-specific issue?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with Flutter (see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138207)

Answer (score 0):

you can call
`FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);`
with onPressed of the icon like this:

```dart
IconButton(
                  focusNode: focusNodeButton,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_next),
                  onPressed: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus); //nextFocus is the focusNode to which you want to give focus. you have to assign this focus node that textField 
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: I don't necessarily have access to the next `FocusNode`. My widget could be anywhere in the app

Comment: you can assign it the FocusNode object anywhere in the app.

Comment: Yes, but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of `TextInputAction.next`, which doesn't need to know what is the next `FocusNode`